# Turn on Gps with cordova periodically

Tags: cordova, gps

I want to create an app with cordova that must turn on and turn off the gps periodically, the user must not active gps manually. Is it possible and how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this  [cordova plugin to turn on GPS location manually](https://devpost.com/software/cordova-dialog-gps)

Call this methods of plugins periodically as whenever you want to
   access fine location or configure as per your needs.

```
function calldialog() {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready",function() {
      cordova.dialogGPS("Your GPS is Disabled, this app needs to be enable to      works.",//message
                    "Use GPS, with wifi or 3G.",//description
                    function(buttonIndex){//callback
                      switch(buttonIndex) {
                        case 0: break;//cancel
                        case 1: break;//neutro option
                        case 2: break;//user go to configuration
                      }},
                      "Please Turn on GPS",//title
                      ["Cancel","Later","Go"]);//buttons
     });
     }
```

Comment: @asv if this helps you,please accept the answer and upvote !! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn on the location service automatically because its related to **user privacy**. So whenever you want to turn on the location service you must required the user permission. Following plugin may use full to u to turn on the location service with user permission.

https://github.com/rodrigo-martinezd/cordova-dialog-gps